# Create multiple full screen divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a single page website, with multiple divs that are full screen, but I'm not being able to turn them full screen.
I'm Already using bootstrap to make the website responsive, and it's my first time doing that.
What I want to do is set a background video, then when I scroll down, the divs fitting the entire viewport

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="imagens/logo_icone.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <title>Museu do Barro Preto</title>

</head>

<body>  
<div class="container-fluid">
                          <!--Video -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <video class="video_bg" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="video/prom.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        A extensão do ficheiro não é suportada pelo seu browser
    </video>
    </div>
      </div>
     <!--/Video -->

  <!--Barra de Navegação-->
    <div class="row">
    <header class="col-md-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#texto1">Quem Somos</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Onde Estamos</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Educação</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Video</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Exposições</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
<!--/Barra de Navegação-->

<div class="row pag1">
    <article class="col-md-8">
        <section>
            <h1>Quem Somos</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque iaculis mattis odio, vitae aliquet orci porttitor quis. Morbi feugiat nulla sit amet felis rutrum, sed iaculis augue porta. Morbi semper et enim in ultricies. Morbi consectetur lorem sodales, maximus risus in, lacinia ex. Nulla metus risus, luctus in quam ut, maximus viverra sem. Nulla posuere condimentum hendrerit. Nulla pulvinar dictum magna non euismod. Quisque et elit nunc. Aenean non dignissim lectus. Ut et purus ac mauris luctus tempor.

Praesent elit quam, eleifend ac aliquet id, imperdiet a est. Nam gravida sed nunc at elementum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean.</p>
        </section>
    </article>

    <aside class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://www.dueceira.pt/trilhos/imgs/barro_preto_vnp2.jpg" alt="Peças Barro Preto">
    </aside>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <article>
        <aside class="col-md-4">

        <div id="mapa">

        </div>
    </aside>

        <section class="col-md-8">
                        <h1>Onde Estamos</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque iaculis mattis odio, vitae aliquet orci porttitor quis. Morbi feugiat nulla sit amet felis rutrum, sed iaculis augue porta. Morbi semper et enim in ultricies. Morbi consectetur lorem sodales, maximus risus in, lacinia ex. Nulla metus risus, luctus in quam ut, maximus viverra sem. Nulla posuere condimentum hendrerit. Nulla pulvinar dictum magna non euismod. Quisque et elit nunc. Aenean non dignissim lectus. Ut et purus ac mauris luctus tempor.

Praesent elit quam, eleifend ac aliquet id, imperdiet a est. Nam gravida sed nunc at elementum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean.</p>
        </section>
    </article>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div id="ilustracao">
        <h1>SLIDESHOW DAS ILUSTRAÇÕES</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="video">
    <div id="documentario">
    <h1>Documentario</h1>
        <video class="documentario" controls>
            <source src="video/prom.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>

        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}

html>body .pag1 {
  height:auto;
}
.video_bg { 
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

 .borders {
    border: 1px solid black;
 }

 .documentario {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
 }

 .pag1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
 }

 .pag1 img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
 }
```

Comment: You'll have to clarify a bit about what _"filling the viewport"_ means and what exactly the behavior is that you want. Do you want your DIVs to have the same dimensions as the viewport but not initially fill it?

Comment: i want them to be fullscreen,if u can understand

Comment: That's what I'm trying to clarify. Fullscreen sounds like you'd be removing the ability to scroll. Should the DIVs have the same dimensions as the viewport but come one after another when you scroll? i.e. viewport is 1200x800 so each DIV should be 1200x800?

Comment: No sorry, my bad, i didn´t clarify correctly, what i want is to have is multiple div, that fill the viewport, despite the content, and to be able to scroll.

Comment: Dude, that's what you said in your question. Perhaps a simple diagram? [Is this what you're looking to do](https://jsfiddle.net/9npd6zj5/)?

Comment: I want to create the feeling of being another page, but in fact it's all in one page

Comment: Yes, that want i'm tryng to do

Comment: Then that is what @JBaldwin has provided in their answer. Use viewport units. `100vh` will match the height of the viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving your div's a vh style. Such as

div {max-height:100vh;} // this will give your div a max height of 100 vertical height which is set to full screen size.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the vh unit, coupled with a fallback for browsers that don't support it. Unless it's a very big project (those scroll-y sites usually aren't) I'd ditch Bootstrap. It's pretty badly made, actually.

Last site we did that had to behave like that, we put each full-screen element in a li, sized the li using 100vh, falling back to regular px units set by javascript to match screen size, falling back to a set of common screen resolutions through conditional comments.

Sadly, using 100% created a lot of headaches with sizing child elements.

This is elaborate to set up, but if you do this once it will save you a lot of work later. It's also pretty much the only solid way to do this accessibly. (We test all our work through a group of users with assistive technology.)

So In essence:

```
<ol>
   <li>
       'Page' content here.
   </li>
   <li>
       'Page'content here.
   </li>
</ol>


ol {
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 100%; /* Caused no issues and is better supported */
height: auto;
float: left;
}

li {
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
float: left;
}
```

Look at Modernizr if you haven't already:

https://modernizr.com/

Also look at the various Javascript solutions for serving up compatible video formats, or you may find yourself showing a full-screen blank screen.

Oh, and insert obligatory warning here about video aspect ratio's not matching all screen aspect ratio's. ;-)